# Баг при парсинге

Tags: jsoup, java, android

Я использую библиотеку jsoup для разбора xml одной rss ленты, однако выражение вида:

```
newsRaw.select("link").text();
```

всегда возвращает пустую строчку, что удивительно, поскольку все остальные тэги, вроде title и description, обрабатываются нормально. Быть может, к link нужен особый подход?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Document newsRaw = Jsoup.parse(response.body(), "", Parser.xmlParser());
newsRaw.select("link").text();
```

Comment: Хорошо, а что такое response.body()?

Comment: @nekaneka: судя по всему, текст http-ответа (то есть, то, что надо распарсить).

Comment: Спасибо, получилось.